# 403-page in Django

Tags: django

I use Django 1.4. I created 403.html file in the same directory as 404.html (404 error page works fine). Yes, I read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view). Then I turn off cookies in my browser, try to login and see the default 403-error page, not mine 403.html page:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
More information is available with DEBUG=True.
```

I restarted Apache, but it doesnt help.

How to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not the default 403-error page. You are seeing this message because the [CSRF middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/) does not work when cookies are disabled.

Your custom 403 template has no effect because the CSRF middleware does not use the general 403 view, but the view defined by the setting [`CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-failure-view), which [is defined in django.conf.global_settings](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/conf/global_settings.py#L531) as `django.views.csrf.csrf_failure`. As you can see [in the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/views/csrf.py), the message you are seeing is hardcoded in the view.

You could create your own [`CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-failure-view), but that is probably not what you want. I suggest you leave everything as it is and just delete the cookies or use another browser to test as unauthenticated user.

Comment: I just want to provide for the situation, if the user goes to the disabled сookie, and that he displayed my page 403. That is, I need to change the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/views/csrf.py)?

Comment: Don't change the Django source! Create a new view and set CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW in your settings. Alternatively, you could check in JavaScript if cookies are enabled and disable login.